# Word Master-Detail Mail Merge

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, master-detail, mailmerge

I searched a lot to find out how to do a "master-detail" style mail merge in word but i couldn't find an appropriate answer/tutorial.

my data look like this:

```
id      name         property
-----------------------------
1       John Doe     employed
1       John Doe     married
1       John Doe     male
2       Don Joe      employed
2       Don Joe      single
2       Don Joe      male
```

and the result should look like this:

[image: word]

with a page-break between every key record.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved through a Microsoft Word Mail Merge?

(i know SSRS,etc.. are better tools for this, but i have to use MS Word because on the client this is the only thing that's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - this is possible using WORDs mail merge.
I don't think you can do it with your data the way it is now. There's not much that can be done to manipulate the data before it gets to the mail merge.

You would need to clean up the data to combine the properties for each person into one field before you can do the merge.

Is your data in Excel? You can write some VBA to combine the properties field.

If it's in a database, you can use SQL to combine the fields using For XML Path.

Once your data is cleaned up, you would be able to use the Mail Merge Wizard.

For the Doc Type, select Letter and use a blank page (current document).

Then select your data.

The next step is to Write Your Letter. Type your field name (i.e. **Name: **) and click on the Insert Merge Field and select the field to insert.

Repeat for all you fields.

Comment: OK i think i know what you mean. Data are stored in SQL Server , so FOR XML is no problem. So Properties could be one Mergefield delimited by CR+LF?